# Editable / Dragable TimeTable for shift-planning

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, drag-and-drop

i only want to ask, if anyone knows a plugin or anything that allows to edit a shift planner by drag and drop. I startet to coding by self but its pretty extensive.

I need it in any format like this:
[image: Dragable Timebar]

Like u see, an hour is splitted to 4 cells (a 15 minutes), in each tablecell i put a div.bar for represent the whole timeline that shows the complete shift of an employee.

For now it works to drag the whole bar, but i need to expand or shrink the bar in both directions too.

When the mouseup event call, i want to get the id of the entry or the id of the employee and the new start- and endtime, u know?

Anyone knows a good tool/plugin for that?

I have codet an algorythm that creates a shift planner by an array of Employees, now i need to fit it like i explain.